# Python: get variable type for nested types

Tags: python

Is there anything that I can use at a breakpoint, to examine a variable and explain it in plain English (?)

Something like [cDecl](https://cdecl.org/) (although that works at compile time, not run time), that will tell me, for instance, that my variable is a list of dictionaries of lists, or similar complex structure.

`type()` just gives me the outermost type; it doesn't iterate all the way down.

Comment: What type would you want reported for something like `[True, 3, {'a': 9.3}]`?

Comment: Why can't you just write an expression for the component of the variable you are interested in and use `type` on that?

Comment: you could recursively traverse your object and apply `type()` to each component

Comment: possibly with proper type hinting/variable annotation, you can avoid the need for this

Comment: Are you using PyCharm? You can use the evaluate expression button (looks like a little calculator) in the debug window to see the type of any expression you want.

Comment: I ***am*** using PyCharm (what else? :-), but it doesn't show it in cleartext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Tried to make the output a little more instructive - need to change from `f-string` notation if < Python 3.6

I don't know of anything that does that as a standard function. 
I think you could use something like the following to get close though:

```
def type_iter(xobj, nest_level):
    print(f'Level {nest_level}: {type(xobj)}')
    if isinstance(xobj, dict):
        for k, v in xobj.items():
            print(f'Level {nest_level+1}: Dict key - {type(k)}')
            type_iter(v, nest_level+1)
    else:
        try:
            for i in xobj:
                type_iter(i, nest_level+1)
        except TypeError as te:
            pass
            #print(x, 'is not iterable')
```

Comment: I presume that I call it with `nest_level` set to zer0?  Whatever I do, it stackoverflows (in Python 3.7)

Comment: You can call it with whatever you like, I used `0`, but it’s just being used in the `print` statements to tell you how deep into the nesting you are, so it shouldn’t cause any problems at all. With the exact error message and some idea of what you’re passing in as `xobj` I might be able to help you.